# Send email from Azure app service with sender as my domain email

Tags: azure, email

Here is what I want to achieve: I want to send email to clients from a .NET core based web-api hosted on Azure. And I want the email's sender address to be "info@mydomain.com".. which "mydomain.com" is the domain I own from GoDaddy.

I have done some search but surprisingly haven't found any easy to follow tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using MailKit.

```
    public void SendMessage(MimeMessage message)
    {
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

            client.Connect("smtp_host", 465, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);

            client.Authenticate("admin@mysite", "smtp_password");

            client.Send(message);
            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really simple to use SendGrid, especially with for instance the [Azure Functions SendGrid bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp).

For an approach where you use the SendGrid NuGet package, see [How to Send Email Using SendGrid with Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email).

> This guide demonstrates how to perform common programming tasks with the SendGrid email service on Azure. The samples are written in C# and supports .NET Standard 1.3. The scenarios covered include constructing email, sending email, adding attachments, and enabling various mail and tracking settings.